# Csv and text editor showing different values

Tags: csv, text-editor

When I open the csv , it shows 0.103945 as value . But when i open it in text editor the value is shown as 0.10394500000000001 . Why this problem occurs when we open in csv and text editor?

Because of this issue I'm having problems. Is there any way to fix this issue and the csv is generated through java code.

Comment: The problem isn't the text editor but the other program that converts the string `0.10394500000000001` to a number without notifying the user about the potential rounding issues

Comment: `When I open the csv`, What software do you use to open the csv file?

Answer (score 0):

A decimal cannot be exactly represented in binary, and 0.103945 will be represented differently in a 32-bit and 64-bit floating point value.
A 32-bit number is represented by approximately six decimal digits, while a 564-bit number is represented by sixteen